# PF1 Swashbuckler in pcgen

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen, swashbuckler

I'm creating a PF1 Human Swashbuckler. As a class ability, he gets "Swashbuckler Finesse", which allows him to use Finesse on single-handed as well as light melee weapons. I equip him with a cutlass, and add the feat Weapon Focus (cutlass). RAW, I should now be able to give him the Slashing Grace feat, but pcgen doesn't allow it. The Requirements text has "all of ( at least 1 Weapon Finesse FEAT )" in red. I add a GM bonus of an extra feat, and apply Weapon Finesse. Now Slashing Grace shows up in black, but selecting it and clicking Add Selected does nothing. Is there any way I can get this to work?
Using version 6.08.00 RC8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the rules below, it should in fact work.

The error you see reported in red, indicates it isn't counting Swashbuckler Finesse as Weapon Finesse:
"all of ( at least 1 Weapon Finesse FEAT )"

This a known issue and in [their bug database](https://pcgenorg.atlassian.net/browse/DATA-4310?jql=text%20%7E%20%22swashbuckler%20finesse%22). It has not currently been fixed, but a pull request has been submitted.

There is also [another bug](https://pcgenorg.atlassian.net/browse/DATA-4260) that prevents taking Slashing Grace even when you have taken Weapon Finesse. This bug has been in the system since Aug 2021.

The first bug has a PR (a patch from a third party submitted to the developers). The second does not have a PR attached, so the developer would need to solve the issue.

Swashbuckler Finesse says:

> gains the benefits of the Weapon Finesse feat with light or one-handed **piercing** melee weapons, and she can use her Charisma score in place of Intelligence as a prerequisite for combat feats. This ability counts as having the Weapon Finesse feat for purposes of meeting feat prerequisites.

A cutlass is defined as:

> Damage 1d4 (small), 1d6 (medium); Critical 18-20/x2; Range —; **Type S**;
> Category One-Handed

Slashing Grace has the following rules:

> Choose one kind of light or one-handed **slashing** weapon (such as the longsword). When wielding your chosen weapon one-handed, you can treat it as a one-handed **piercing** melee weapon for all feats and class abilities that require such a weapon

Comment: Thanks for your answer @James Risner, but my main problem is that even after I add Weapon Finesse, I'm still unable to add Slashing Grace.  The red "missing prerequisite" text is gone, but the feat doesn't appear on the RHS when I click on "Add Selected"!  AS I've added a GM-bonus feat, I still have one feat available to assign.

Comment: Also, is the PcGen bug database still being worked on?

Comment: Their most recent activity was 2 days ago (12/28/22), so yes. Issues like this really need a PR from users. I imagine the developers spent most of their time taking PR, testing, and integrating them.